# Getting Recv-Q/Send-Q in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, winsock

In linux, you can get the following statistics with netstat:

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.136.58519    72.47.210.69.80        LAST_ACK
tcp4      37      0  192.168.1.136.57059    174.129.27.181.443     CLOSE_WAIT
tcp4      37      0  192.168.1.136.57058    174.36.30.66.443       CLOSE_WAIT
```

But the windows version of netstat doesn't seem to provide Recv-Q/Send-Q. Is there an advanced tool available somewhere, or do I have to talk to some *.dll to get them in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Performance Monitoring tool (perfmon) to find out some of this information.

Add a counter from the "Network Interface" performance monitor.  There are a number of options including the "Output Queue Length".

Comment: My understanding is Recv-Q/Send-Q are IP level statistics, while "Output Queue Length" is NIC level. Is this correct?

Comment: @ento that's correct. Also Output Queue Length is always 0. For anyone else searching for this, check out this question too: http://serverfault.com/questions/67427/how-do-i-view-the-tcp-send-and-receive-queue-sizes-on-windows